# Table API Scala

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am trying to join two tables using flink scala table api. I have one table with two(a,b) columns and another table with one (c)column i want to join the two tables to a bigger table having three(a, b, c) columns. I simply want to join them i don't want to use any condition(Where clause) to join them. But Flink throws me an error to use Where clause, is it a way to join the table without any condition in the where clause? if i wan to use where clause what condition should i give?

Below is my command for joining two tables

```scala
val table_join = table1.join(table2).select("a,b,c").toDataset[res]
```

any help in the right direction is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Apache Flink's Table API join is an inner equi-join and requires at least one equality predicate.

Joins without predicates are cross products. Flink's Table API does not offer an operator for cross product, because cross products are **very** expensive to compute.

With Flink's DataSet API, cross products can be computed using cross operator or a map function with a Broadcast set.

Comment: What you could do as a work around, though, is to assign an additional column which contains for each row the same value. If you join on this column, then you basically simulate a cross operation.